# I got "TypeError: string indices must be integers" even though I'm using integers

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm pretty early on in python (only learning for loop right now) and I have gotten into a bit of a problem.

[image: a picture of my code]

As you can see I am using integers (as I have checked using `type()`) but is still raises the TypeError. Any idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read
[the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). [do not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557); [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not helpful.

Comment: `0,6` is a tuple, not an integer.

Comment: Use a colon (:) instead of a comma on line 8

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do with your code rather than just the code and the error. Looks like you only need `print(my_string.split(','))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line 8 where you are trying to break a string into multiple parts, but with a wrong syntax. You will have to perform [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) operation as

```
item = my_string[:6] # starting index is 0 by default, and final index is 6-1, i.e., 5
item = my_string[0:6] # starting index is 0, and final index is 6-1, i.e., 5
item = my_string[0:6:1] # starting index is 0, and final index is 6-1, i.e., 5, with a jump of 1 character to the right, i.e., index 0,1,2,3,4 and 5.
```

any of which will produce the same result, instead of

```
item = my_string[0,6]
```

as this will return `TypeError` which you can easily verify by just executing

```
"Hello"[0,6]
```

PS: You can achieve the same end result by doing

```
print(my_string.split(','))
```

as suggested by OneCricketeer. Also, if you want the user to input the string, try this

```
grocery_list = input("enter a comma separated string without spaces: ").split(',')
print(grocery_list)
```

Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that comma `,` to index the string. You have to use colon `:`
Correct syntax of [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) is (start:stop[:step])

```py
item = mystring[0:6] # start at index 0, stop at index 6 (not included)
item = mystring[:6] # same notation, start at index 0
```

Comment: i am well aware if that but when using the method "find" it is supposed to be a comma

Answer (score 0):

This is just a syntax problem. If you want to get all characters up to index 6, you need to do

```
my_string[0:6]
```

In practice, you would usually use a shorter version (with the same functionality):

```
my_string[:6]
```

Additionally, in your code, you probably want to do

```
my_string[pos1:pos2]
```

Currently, you get `pos1` and `pos2` but don't use it.

Lastly, you could have searched "How to get the first 6 characters from a string in Python", and you might have found the answer yourself, e.g. [here](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-get-first-n-characters-in-a-string/). Searching for your problem online and finding a solution is perhaps the most important skill you need now :)

Happy coding!

Comment: firstly, i did use the pos1 pos2 since they are redifined every repetition of the loop, but it gave me the syntax error so i checked they where integers and at last replacced them altogether with two numbers to make sure i am using integers

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_list(my_string):
my_string += ' '
grocery_list = []
pos1 = 0
for item in range(my_string.count(",") + 1):
    pos2 = my_string.find(",", pos1)
    grocery_list += [my_string[pos1:pos2]]
    pos1 = pos2+1
print(grocery_list)
```

call the function make_list('tomato,apple,orange')
This code work in my computer. I hope you get solution of your question.